# Is there any alternative to bmtoa on Mac OS

Tags: macos, unix, bitmap

I have an old Unix shell script that requires the use of bmtoa but I am unable to find it on Mac, and there isn't much on how to install it. Is there any way to get it supported on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

[`bmtoa`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bmtoa) is an X11 tool, and is installed as part of the [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/) package.